# mvc4 breakup a foreach loop into 2 sections

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a foreach loop on my website that gathers 10 records from the database and displays them. What I would like to do is isolate the 1st record and then show the other 9 afterwards. I basically want to show an ad between record 1 and 2-9 so it will be like this

Record 1

Advertisement

Record 2-10

is there any way I can break my foreach loop like that or would I have to make another call to the database? This is my Foreach loop that gathers all 10 records

```
          @foreach (var item in Model.IEThreadpost)
        {
 //content here
        }
```

any suggestions would be great

Comment: Display the first using `Model.IEThreadpost[0]`, then the 'Advertisement' then `for(int i = 1; i < Model.IEThreadpost.Count; i++) { Model.IEThreadpost[i] }`

Comment: Thanks a lot that just solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get record 1 you could use `Model.IEThreadpost.OrderBy(x => x.Entity_ID_HERE).First()`

to use foreach to skip one and get the rest.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.IEThreadpost.OrderBy(x => x.Entity_ID_HERE).Skip(1).Take(9)) //i think skip and take needs ordering
  {

  }
```